# Where on an Android device can I find information about the make, model, etc of the device?

Tags: samsung, system-info

I don't own a smartphone and I don't use Android but other than that I'm a tech guy (-:

My father has a Samsung Android phone but doesn't know what model it is and it has no markings on the case. I want to find out the specs of his phone.

I expect there must be some app or settings on every Android device, or possibly a proprietary Samsung one, that tells us all kinds of info about the phone.

But neither of us can find it. What should I find and click on any arbitrary Android (or Samsung) device?

Comment: `that tells us all kinds of info about the phone.` is way too vague. What exactly you wanted to know?

Comment: User dktr.k1 did not find it vague at all, though their answer didn't quite match my father's device.

Comment: @hippietrail What kind of specs do you need? There are tons of technical specs (what CPU/GPU, screen resolution and dots-per-pixel, hardware revisions, and more). If you only need the "very basics", the on-board solution offered by dktr.k1 will suffice. If you need further details, you might need a 3rd party app (or specific technical knowledge to extract those details e.g. via [tag:adb]). That's what AADTechnical means by "too vague" (just mentioning this in case there's a language barrier on your end ;)

Comment: As mentioned I just wanted to find what model it was. The submitted answer told me how to find that. Now that I know the model number I can easily Google any of the other specs. This question wasn't about directly getting all the technical specs. So maybe my wording was a bit vague blurring that I wanted the model number and what I wanted it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices have an item called *About phone* or *About device* – usually directly in the *Settings* menu (scroll to the very end), but some manufacturers like *Samsung* often move it into a Sub-Menu like *Settings › System.*

That page gives you the most essential details, but by far not all. If what you need cannot be found there, you might need [3<sup>rd</sup> party tools for System Information](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo) like [SysHard Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kinocat.andinfo) – or, with some technical background and knowledge, can explore system internals via [adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info), e.g. using the `adb dumpsys` command.

Comment: Do you mean Settings -> System -> About phone/device? Or is this something that varies by Android version or due to Samsung-specific proprietary changes?

Comment: for me it is Settings -> About Phone. but the exact way to get there depends on the android version, might also have a slight change on your Samsung device... do you know which year it was released? can you remove the battery?

Comment: No we didn't know any of those details but managed to find it now due to your help, despite the difference with his device. Thanks.

Comment: great! please edit my amswer to suit the right method and mark it as the right answer. or post an answer yourself (:

Comment: @dktr.k1 I took the freedom to expand it a bit. As it was, it rather looked like a comment :) Hope this edit is OK for you; feel free to adjust it if it's not.

Comment: @Izzy thanx for the edit and extension!  I am satisfied with it (: